# Signal R in Aurelia framework

Tags: signalr-hub, signalr.client, aurelia

I am trying to integrate signal r in Aurelia client application.
I already have signalr server up and running which is running with other framework like durandal.
My Hub URl is like this "http://localhost/signalr/signalr/hubs"

Steps to add signalr in client

1. Adding jquery.signalR-{version}.js in index.html
2. adding   "http://localhost/signalr/signalr/hubs" in index.html
3. add connection start block in app.js

> ```
>  $.connection.notificationHub.connection.start().done(
>             function () {
>                 console.log('hurray, connection established');               
>             }
>             ).fail(function () {
>                 console.log('oops - connection failed');
>             });
> ```

Now on running app following error is seen can not find notificationHub of undefined

please let me know where is the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I have added SignalR into an Aurelia app by *not* using the generated proxy and just doing it manually, as per the instructions [on this page](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client). I created a separate module but I guess you could use it in the app.js instead. You need to add something like:

```
...    
// Create a connection -> create a proxy -> attach event handlers -> start
this.connection = $.hubConnection('http://my.signalr.host.here');
this.hubProxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('myHubName');
this.connection.logging = true;

// Add method handler(s)
this.hubProxy.on('myMethodCalledByTheServer', e => {
    console.log('SignalR called us', e);
});

// Connect to SignalR events if required. eg:
this.connection.connectionSlow(() => {
    console.log('The SignalR connection is slow');
});

// Start
this.connection.start()
    .then(c => {
        console.log('Started', c);
    });
```

Call a server method using the following:

```
this.hubProxy.invoke('myServerMethod', args);
```

In the function handlers we use the Aurelia event-aggregator to publish appropriate messages to the rest of the app.

By using the manual approach you don't need to include the signalr/hubs script in index.html.

Comment: @PranayVerma - you have your answer, so mark it accepted. That will make it easier to find with search engines.